# PHP echo objects property that is prepended with sum

Tags: php, sum

In PHP I'm returning the sum of two columns and getting back an object of:

```
stdClass Object ( [sum(`total`)] => 54.00 [sum(`word_count`)] => 90 )
```

I'm trying to loop through this with a foreach

```
foreach($Classified as $classified) {
    echo $classified->total;
    echo $classified->sum;
}
```

returns the error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object. I suspect the sum is somehow throwing it off?

Comment: In your SQL query, use aliases.  ``SELECT SUM(`total`) AS sum, SUM(`word_count`) AS total ...``

Comment: Your fields are *not* named `'sum'` and/or `'total'`.  They are ``'sum(`total`)'`` and ``'sum(`word_count`)'``.  I suggest using aliases in your SQL query (as explained in my 1st comment).  Otherwise, you can try ``$classified->{'sum(`total`)'}``.

Comment: $classified->{"[sum(`total`)"} maybe? but yeah @RocketHazmat is correct sort out the sql so it returns cleaner names

Comment: @TomChew-headMillard: Wrap the code block in 2 backticks if the code inside contains backticks:  ```Like this: ``$classified->{'sum(`total`)'}``.``` :-D

Comment: Thanks guys/girls the alias worked perfectly.